# Change name of series in chart with Pandas excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, charts

I want to add a bar chart to my excel file using Pandas from Python, but I don't seem to be able to change the name of the Series.

This is my code:

```
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'bar'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=DoneRFQ!$B$2:$B$3', 'categories':'=DoneRFQ!$A$2:$A$3'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=DoneRFQ!$C$2:$C$3', 'categories':'=DoneRFQ!$A$2:$A$3'})
donesheet.insert_chart('B5', chart)
```

How can I change the name of the blue and red series `('Series1' and 'Series2')`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `name` attribute:

```
chart.add_series({
'name': 'first name',
'categories': '=DoneRFQ!$A$2:$A$3',
'values': '=DoneRFQ!$B$2:$B$3'})

chart.add_series({
'name': 'second name',
'categories': '=DoneRFQ!$A$2:$A$3',
'values': '=DoneRFQ!$C$2:$C$3'})
```